# swift com sqlite

Tags: ios, swift

Estou tentando criar um banco sqlite com o swift, mas estou tendo dificuldades quanto a exemplos e documentacao na net, queria ver se alguem conseguiu conectar em um banco sqlite com o swift ?

Comment: Não tem muita coisa ainda, mas achei um link no SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102775/accessing-an-sqlite-database-in-swift

Comment: Vlw helderdarocha esse link caiu como uma luva...

Comment: Aproveitando eu achei esse link tbm..
http://swiftplayground.com.br/

Comment: Experimenta ver no www.swift.pt tem la bons exemplos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma aplicação demo no github, que pode ser uma boa para vc entender como fazer a conexao com o sqlite e como utiliza-lo juntamente com o swift.

Veja o projeto exemplo no link abaixo:

https://github.com/rnystrom/Swift-CoreData#swift--core-data

Espero que ajude a resolver seu problema.